# How to resize Kivy TextInput form box while keeping the Text in the middle of the box?

Tags: python, kivy, frontend, textinput

I have the following Kivy TextInput:

but when I type into it via `PhoneInput().text += {TEXT_ENTERED}`, the text shows up in the bottom right corner of the screen, way away from the TextInput Box that I centered on screen with the Property `pos=ListProperty([200,265])`.

How do I keep that TextInput box in place and also get the Text to show inside that box? Below is my widget:

```
class PhoneInput(TextInput):
    max_characters = NumericProperty(12)
    pos = ListProperty([200,265])
    font_size = NumericProperty(30)
    size_hint=ListProperty([.21,.1])
    color = ListProperty([0,0,0,1])
    cursor_blink = BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_close(), self)

    def on_parent(self, widget, parent):
        self.unfocus_on_touch = False

phoneInput = PhoneInput()
```

Comment: @FadiAbuRaid I added that, but erroring out with 
```File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 116, in do_layout
     for key, value in c.pos_hint.items():
 AttributeError: 'ObservableList' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Sorry relative position should be a dictionary. Try this pos_hint={'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.5}

Comment: Thanks! That didn't move the cursor to the center, but was able to bring the Input box and cursor into the bottom left where I can finally see them together.